# Issue with Ember.Select multiple not updating controller

Tags: ember.js, html-select, ember.select

I have created a little demo, and `selectionBinding` is only working when `multiple="true"` is **not** set.

Here is the code.

```
{{view Ember.Select multiple=true content=sampleData
       optionValuePath="content.value"
       optionLabelPath="content.label"
       selectionBinding=testBinding}} // Multi select does not update controller

{{view Ember.Select content=sampleData
       optionValuePath="content.value"
       optionLabelPath="content.label"
       selectionBinding=testBinding2}} // Single select does update controller
```

**Example: http://jsbin.com/ojAvIPA/1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe arrays in Ember is using `.observes('array.@each')`. You can also use `.observes('array.length')` to observe the length of the array.

**jsbin**: http://jsbin.com/ojAvIPA/5/

Comment: Thanks, I knew you could do that, I just didn't know you had to :)